# Split reg expression

Tags: java

I am trying to split one string as follows

```
String str="COMPLEX:[A(100),B(0)][80]:[B(100),A(0)][20]";
String [] tokens = str.split("[\\[\\]]");
```

Output expected:

```
COMPLEX:
A(100),B(0)
80
B(100),A(0)
20
```

But above reg epx in split function gives me output with extra new lines like

```
[0]->COMPLEX:
[1]->
[2]->A(100),B(0)
[3]->
[4]->80 so on
```

How can I eliminate the extra lines?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be getting the extra newline on 1, but you should get the one on 3, because your regex matches both the closing ] and the opening [, so it is splitting twice at ][.
Look into expressions being greedy or not.

Probably this will be fixed by also including ][ in your expression, maybe like so:
     `"[\\[\\]]+"`

Having the `+` there will make the expression look for as much brackets next to each other as possible. So it will only split once at `][`, because `][` matches the expression.

[Read this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) if you are interested in understanding regex greediness and laziness.

(edit:) Also, after 80 you will definitely get `:` as well. If you don't want that, adjust your regex accordingly. (You do want the colon after COMPLEX, so you can't just add the colon in the range)
Something like this: `"[\\[\\]]+:?[\\[\\]]*"`

Comment: You're welcome! Also read my edit if you do want to end up with your expected output and not have the colon in between as well.